# How to test sign-up flow with 'Sign in with Apple'

Tags: ios, authentication, apple-sign-in

We're building a sign-up flow using 'Sign up with Apple'.

It seems fairly straightforward, but we can't find a good way to test sign ups. You have to use a real account, which means you can only ever sign up once. This is terrible for QA.

Has anyone found a good way round this? Are there any hacks that would allow us to create new Apple accounts for example?

Comment: You can remove a Sign In with Apple account association by going into the Apple ID settings on the device.

Answer (score 5):

You can revoke Sign In With Apple account association and test it again.

1. Go to iPhone Settings and select Apple Id
2. Go Password & Security
3. Apple ID logins
4. Select {YOUR APP}
5. Stop using Apple ID

Comment: As I found, you may try that, but in fact on the next sign-up you will get the very same user ID which is already registered at the target app and you will have same user in the end. @Bilal, is it something that you have or do you have another userid?

Comment: Yes that’s right. In order to test new signup you have to delete user record from your backend and revoke the Sign In With Apple and test it again.